# How to fix "The imported project "some-path\AspNet\Microsoft.Web.AspNet.Props" was not found."?

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, asp.net-core-mvc

Visual Studio Online and gated checkin, ASP.NET vNext project.

I have a solution with asp.net vnext project (*.kproj extension)
Enable gated checkin on Visual Studio Online and enable unit tests for each checkin.
After checkin in logs error:
*C:\a\src\Dev\project\MyProj\MyProj.kproj (7): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\AspNet\Microsoft.Web.AspNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.*

How to solve this error and what is this "Microsoft.Web.AspNet.Props"? In solution and projects I don't see refereces or something else with name "Microsoft.Web.AspNet.Props"?

Why used v11.0 version? I think should be used v14.0.

Comment: V14 is Visual Studio 2015 which is not yet released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build servers provided by Microsoft as part of the hosted build service are production servers and don't run pre-release software.

If you want to have a build server with Visual Studio 2015 (v14) then you will need to create one yourself. You can easily use your MSDN allowance to create and run a build server on Azure.